# Dependence of energy of solution of IVP on the initial condition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

Let $f$ be a smooth function $[0, L] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,  and consider an initial value problem (IVP) of the form
$$
\begin{cases}
x' = f(t, x),\\
x(0) = x_{0} \in [0, 2\pi).
\end{cases}
$$
In particular, suppose that the problem is globally solvable, meaning that, for any $L$, a solution $[0, L] \to \mathbb{R}$ exists and is unique.

Now, consider a *strictly positive* function of the form
$$
E(x_{0}) = \int_{0}^{L} F(t, x(t), x'(t))\, dt,
$$
where $F(t, x(t), x'(t)) >0$, and where $x$ is a solution of the IVP defined by the initial condition $x_{0}$. The function $E$ may be thought of as assigning an energy to each solution of the IVP (i.e., to the physical system that the IVP represents).

I am wondering if anything interesting can be said about the dependence of the energy $E$ on the initial condition.

It seems plausible to me that, as $L \to \infty$, the dependence of $E$ on $x_{0}$ should become less and less important. In other words, I would expect that, for any $x_{0}, x_{1} \in [0, 2\pi)$,
$$
\lim _{L \to 0} E(x_{0})/E(x_{1}) =1.
$$

**Question.** Is my expectation  justifiable from a mathematical perspective?

Edit: As the answer appears to be *no* in general, I would like to specialize the question to a function $F$ of the form

$$F(t, x(t), x'(t)) = \cos(x(t))^{2} g(t)^{2}.$$

Comment: If you have no additional info on $F$ (and, incidentally, $E$) you can say virtually nothing about $E(x_0)/E(x_1)$

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Thanks for your feedback! I have now added some details about the specific function $F$ I am interested in.

Comment: Possible counter-example: If there is no dependence on $t$ in $f$ and $F$, and if the solutions all converge to an equilibrium, then the contributions to the energy at larger times will be increasingly small, thus unlikely to erase the initial differences.

Comment: @LutzLehmann in your edit, $g(t) = x'(t)$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy : What edit? In the question, as $x'$ is declared on the left side, the $g$ on the right side is some other time-dependent function. It is now a semantic question if the integral should be called "energy" or "action" or something else, as usually the integrand is identified with the energy. If a time average is meant, the division by $L$ is missing.

Comment: @LutzLehmann my apologies, I wanted to tab-complete on the OP's name and somehow got yours. Terribly sorry=)